# AudioQueueStart returns 561015905 (AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotStartPlaying)

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, audioqueue

My app uses Audio Queue Services to play sounds. On app start, I set audio session category to solo ambient:

```
`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSEssionCategorySoloAmbient error:&error];`
```

When my app delegate gets `applicationWillResignActive` notification, I call `AudioQueuePause(queue);` for all playing sounds. And when the app delegate gets `applicationDidBecomeActive`, I call

```
OSStatus status = AudioQueueStart(queue, 0);
```

Sometimes (and it's hard to reproduce) `status` equals to 561015905. This value does not belong to [Audio Queue Result Codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117-CH5g-RCM0127). It is `AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotStartPlaying`, and docs say

> *"The app is not allowed to start recording and/or playing, usually because of a lack of audio key in         its Info.plist.  This could also
>   happen if the app has this key but uses a category that can't record
>
>         and/or play in the background (AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient,
>   AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient, etc.)."*

I definitely do not want to play the sound in background (that's why I am pausing audio queues when app resigns active). So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well the Apple document for the [AudioQueueStart API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioQueueStart )states that it "Begins playing or recording audio" so maybe you just shouldn't make this call. Are you needing the OSStatus for something else? Also, the second parameter to that method is of type AudioTimeStamp so maybe it expects either NULL or an actual struct and not 0.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but I made a little in a different way...There was musical app in which background music was necessary, but under certain conditions she has to howled to play in background mode.
For me, i use this code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
  AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@property (assign) SystemSoundID pewPewSound;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSURL * pewPewURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"Calypso" withExtension:@"caf"];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pewPewURL error:nil];

     if (audioPlayer)
     {
          [audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:100];
          [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
          [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
          [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
          [audioPlayer play];
     }

}

@end
```

If u don't touch any Xcode setting, this code play looping melody, only in foreground, and if u go to background, player is stopped.

if u do this:

[image]

melody will continue to play in background, and in my case i can stop and play melody in background and foreground  when i want. And I add system sound to call then u stop player, system sound stopped then U continue play music.

```
-(void)stopPlaying
{
    [audioPlayer pause];

    NSURL * pewPewURL;
    pewPewURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"Calypso" withExtension:@"caf"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)pewPewURL, &_pewPewSound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.pewPewSound);
}

-(void)continueToPlay
{
    if ([audioPlayer prepareToPlay])
    {
        [audioPlayer play];
        AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(self.pewPewSound);
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(self.pewPewSound);
    }
}
```

I hope it will help to solve yours problems, If there are questions, set I will answer everything.